# How can I run a sh command in java with assigning options

Tags: java, shell, sh, processbuilder, runtime.exec

So this is my sh command which I currently execute in a sh script:

```
sh bin/vtdStart.sh -project=4 -setup="Sim" -autoConfig >& debug.txt
```

What I want is to execute the script "vtdStart.sh" in java AND setting the project,setup,autoConfig at the same time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the command line you actually want to execute is this:

```
 bin/vtdStart.sh -project=$SM_PROJECT -setup=$SM_SETUP -autoConfig >& debug.txt
```

and that `vtdStart.sh` is has the execute bit(s) set and a `#!/bin/sh` line.

There are two ways to do this:

1. You could do the environment variable interpolation by hand, split the command arguments, pull out the redirection, etc, and put it all together with `ProcessBuilder`.
2. You could do it the easy way:

   ```
   Runtime.exec("/bin/sh", "-c", 
     "bin/vtdStart.sh -project=$SM_PROJECT -setup=$SM_SETUP -autoConfig >& debug.txt");
   ```

   and let the shell deal with the expansion and redirection.